# Different behaviour of 'this' with arrow function in VueJs

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, this, arrow-functions, strict

Alright, there are 3 cases that I want to talk about. I know that arrow functions have lexical scoping and this will propagate outwards until a match is found. However here are some cases where the behaviours are not making sense to me, so some explanation would be great.

**1. Inside a Single File Component's `methods`**

// HelloWorld.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <button @click="nonArrow">click me</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
  methods: {
    nonArrow() {
      console.log(this);
    },
    arrow: () => {
      console.log(this);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

`nonArrow()` displays `VueComponent` instance as usual. `arrow()` displays `undefined` but shouldn't it display `window` ?

**2. Inside Vue component from script tag.**

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
    },
    methods: {
        noArrow() {
            console.log(this);
        },
        arrow: () => {
            console.log(this);
        }
})
```

`noArrow()` gives a `Vue` instance, but `arrow()` gives the `window` object. Why is `window` not being referenced in the previous example?

**3. Using strict mode**

```
methods: {
    noArrow() {
        console.log(this);
    },
    arrow: () => {
        "use strict";
        console.log(this);
    }
}
```

In the 2nd example, if I use strict mode with the arrow function inside the methods, it still outputs `window` object, whereas a normal arrow function defined outside with strict mode will console log `undefined`. What is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

> Don’t use arrow functions on an options property or callback, such as created: () => console.log(this.a) or vm.$watch('a', newValue => this.myMethod()). Since an arrow function doesn’t have a this, this will be treated as any other variable and lexically looked up through parent scopes until found, often resulting in errors such as Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined or Uncaught TypeError: this.myMethod is not a function.

You shouldn't use arrow function. Please refer to this link.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods

Comment: I know I shouldn't use arrow function. I am just trying to understand the reasons for these discrepancies.

Comment: Since an arrow function doesn’t have a `this`, `this` will be treated as any other variable and lexically looked up through parent scopes until found.

Comment: Yes, but where does the lexical scope resolve to in the first example? Why does it show undefined? Which 'this' does it 'match' to?

Comment: It basically means that the arrow function takes `this` from it's context, which means if you try to access `this` from inside of an arrow function that's on a Vue component, you'll get an error because `this` doesn't exist!

Comment: Okay so what is the context of the arrow function here? Its enclosed inside `methods` object.

Comment: arrow functions are bound to the parent context, and therefore `this` will not be the Vue instance as you would expect, this refers to the `Window` object, which is not really what we expected.

Comment: If it does refer to `window` object, why is it printing `undefined` in the first case? The latter cases are pretty clear but the first one's confusing.